# Проверить есть ли свойство объекта в массиве

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Есть массив с объектами. Нужно проверить есть ли данное свойство объекта в массиве с объектами. Пример:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Вася',
    age: 25
  },
  {
    name: 'Петя',
    age: 15
  }
]
```

Как узнать есть ли в массиве объект со свойством `name: 'Вася'`

Answer (score 6):

Метод [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) вернет `true`, в случае, если хотя бы один элемент попадает под условие

```
const a = [
  {
    name: 'Вася',
    age: 25
  },
  {
    name: 'Петя',
    age: 15
  }
]

console.log(a.some(el => el.name === 'Вася'));
```

Comment: Для автора вопроса. В ответе используется стрелочная функция (`=>`).